# The ViewBag content isn't being visualized

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm brand new to `ASP.NET MVC` web development.
And I'm trying to build a website that basically has access to a database which can be filled by user.

Alright, all good, that part works fine. What I'm struggling with, is that whenever the user insert data into the database, I wanna show a message saying that his insertion has been done succesfully, or something like that. I wanna show that down in the form panel.

This is the code that I got so far:

This is the method being called when the user clicks the submit button:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PersonModels person)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here
        //Adding to database and holding the response in the viewbag.
        string strInsertion = ConnectionModels.insertPerson(person);
        ViewBag.InsertionResult = strInsertion;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

And this is my Index action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

And finally, this is what I'm trying to d in my index.cshtml:

```
<div>
     <label>
         @ViewBag.InsertionResult
     </label>
</div>
```

I'm not gonna post it completely 'cause it'd be quite extensive. But that's beneath the div of the form panel.

I hope you can give me a hand.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Exact question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497711/set-viewbag-before-redirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not pass a `ViewBag` value while redirecting to another action. If you are in the same controller you can use `TempData` to pass values in a session otherwise you can pass the message as a parameter to `RedirectionResult` like below:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new {message="Your Message"});
```

and then get it back like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string message)
{
    ViewBag.ViewBag.InsertionResult = message;
    return View();
}
```

This is a general way how to pass messages but I would recommend something like this:

Use a `BaseController` where all controllers inherits from this one:

Here you can make a custom logic how to handle global message like error messages, notification messages, info messages etc.

For that you need to create a model like below:

I am keeping it simple here:

```
public class GlobalMessage
{
   public string Message { get;set;}
   public AlertType AlertType {get;set;}
}
public enum AlertType
{
   Success, Info, Error, Danger//etc
}
```

In `BaseController` you would have something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected GlobalMessage GlobalMessage;
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
        {
            if (GlobalMessage!= null)
            {
                filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.GlobalMessage = GlobalMessage;
            }
            else
            {
                GlobalErrorViewModel globalErrorModelView = TempData["GlobalMessage"] as GlobalMessage;

                if (globalErrorModelView != null)
                {
                    filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.GlobalErrorViewModel = globalErrorModelView;
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }

}
```

In this moment you just have to register new `GlobalMessage` in `Tempdata` like below:

```
public PeopleController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PersonModels person)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            //Adding to database and holding the response in the viewbag.
            string strInsertion = ConnectionModels.insertPerson(person);
            TempData["GlobalMessage"] = new GlobalMessage{ AlertType = AlertType.Info, Message = "You have successfully added a new person" }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Then here is the final step how to show data in the view:

I personally use popup or modal window to do this: For example in bootstrapp you would write something like this:

```
GlobalMessage globalMessage = ViewBag.GlobalMessage as GlobalMessage;
   @if (globalMessage != null)
    {
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="globalMessage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content panel-@globalMessage .AlertType.ToString().ToLower() remove-border-radius">
                    <div class="modal-header panel-heading">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p class="h-text-primary">@Html.Raw(globalMessage .Message)</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-@globalMessage .AlertType.ToString().ToLower() remove-border-radius" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
    }
```

Trigger the modal if there is a message:

```
@if (globalMessage != null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#globalMessage').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
}
```

This example was to show how you can make a system to show different messages. In short terms whatever you want!

Comment: Dang, this was really really helpful! Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: I am glad i helped :)

Answer (score 0):

`ViewBag` and `ViewData` objects will return `null` values after a redirect. Their contents only survive for the duration of the current request.

There's another property, `TempData`, whose contents will endure the current *and subsequent* request, but **only** the subsequent request. However, this means that you can use it to pass data when you call `RedirectToAction`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PersonModels person)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here
        //Adding to database and holding the response in the viewbag.
        string strInsertion = ConnectionModels.insertPerson(person);
        TempData[InsertionResult] = strInsertion;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string strInsertion = TempData[InsertionResult];
    return View("Index", new { InsertionResult = strInsertion });
}

<label>
    @Model.InsertionResult
</label>
```

A good explanation is given here: http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications/

An alternative approach would be for your `Index` view to take an optional view model containing the result of the `HttpPost` that created the Person in your database. You could use that model to populate the contents of your label. Strongly typed models FTW!