# How to Fix:start and end time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

I am trying to displaying start and end time of the for loop but is not displaying.

this my code:

Controller:

```
                    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
                    {
                   UserMaster employee = new UserMaster();
                   employee.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
                   ViewBag.StartTime = "Start Time" + employee.StartTime;

                    for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
                     {
                      employee.Name = collection["Name"]
                      employee.City = collection["City"];
                      employee.Address = collection["Address"];
          UserMasterRepository employeeBusinessLayer = new  UserMasterRepository();
                       employeeBusinessLayer.Add(employee);
                         }

                     employee.EndTime  = DateTime.Now;
                      ViewBag.EndTime ="Start Time" + employee.EndTime;
                      return RedirectToAction("Index");
                   }
```

repository:

userMaster.cs

```
               public class UserMaster
                {
                 public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
                 public DateTime OperatingTime { get; set; }
                 public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
              }
```

View:

```
          model IEnumerable<MVCWithDI.Repository.UserMaster>
          @{
             ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
             Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
          }
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
          {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
              <h4>Customer</h4>
               <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">

                 @ViewBag.StartTime<br />
                 <br />
                  @ViewBag.EndTime<br />
                <br />
                 @ViewBag.time<br />
                 <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-12 text-success">
              </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        }
```

How can I resolve this issue.I am using repository,unity framework.

Comment: please add the remaining code of Create action method and what is the result you got in your view when running

Comment: Did you checked in ViewBag cotains any values? Add remaining for Create action method

Comment: could plz u see I added some more code in create action method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Viewbag before Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497711/set-viewbag-before-redirect)

Comment: @Ravi actually ViewBag data will be lost after redirect which is logic behavior

Comment: How can I resolve this issue in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewBag doesn't contain a value with return RedirectToAction.
You should use `return view("Index")`.
instead of `return RedirectToAction("Index")`.